# Add manually file pac to Proxy with HtmlUnit

Tags: configuration, proxy, htmlunit, pac

Sorry if my english level isn't good.

Can I assign a PAC file to Proxy manually with HtmlUnit?

I've tried assign a URL but Java shows exceptions and I think to add manually the file and I see if the file has any error or not.

Any help? Thanks.